# Warning in Cassandra logs for batch writes

Tags: c++, cassandra-2.0

We are using Cassandra 2.0.10 with the Cassandra C++ Driver 1.0.0.beta4. I am seeing the following lines in my /var/log/cassandra/system.log

WARN [Native-Transport-Requests:83088] 2015-01-08 22:56:15,327 BatchStatement.java (line 226) Batch of prepared statements for [clipmine_prod.tag_attributes, clipmine_prod.tag] is of size 5812, exceeding specified threshold of 5120 by 692.

What does this mean and what is the impact of it? If a batch statement is failing, why is it a warn? We are not aware of what code is executing this either. We have python and C))

We are not using prepared statements as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a warning about the size of your batch, because large batches can result in high pressure on the coordinator node

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.0.10/conf/cassandra.yaml#L436-L438

The statement is not failed. It only produces a warn log:

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.0.10/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql3/statements/BatchStatement.java#L211-L228